# Where does Rails 3 keep its public files if it is bundled as a war?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tomcat, jruby

Running tomcat, i have this folder hierarchy:

```
- manager/
- ROOT/
  - doc
  - docs
  - images
  - javascripts
  - META-INF
  - stylesheets
  - WEB-INF
    - app
    - config
    - ..rails root here?
    - public
      - docs
      - stylesheets
      - system
- ROOT.war
```

Im confused at the two public folders and they both have appropriate files in them. This is just a quick question, it just takes a long time for me to debug by printing out the path(since I don't know how to use the debugger while in a war file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files that Tomcat serves are the ones on the same level as the WEB-INF and META-INF folders, ie. immediately under ROOT. That's how Java EE spec works, and files are copied that way at deploy, the public folder remaining as a vestige from how is usually in Rails.

Comment: Hi clyfe, could you describe your answer using different words to me? I'm not a native English speaker and I don't understand the `remaining as a vestige from how is usually in Rails` part.

Comment: @tolgap It just remains there, not being used.